Service discovery within Kubernetes using an external Eureka instance
I am using Eureka as a service discovery client for one of my services running on a local machine (call it service A). Eureka is also running on this same local machine. I also have a service running in Kubernetes on a separate machine (call it service B). Service B is accessible via an ingress that has been set up on the Kubernetes cluster. I am able to have both services A and B show up on the Eureka page. However, service A is unable to connect to service B via the Eureka client. The Eureka client seems to be sending the pod IP of service B which is not usable by service A since it is outside of the cluster.
Is there a way to get the Eureka service registry to provide a working IP or to pass on the ingress URL to service A? Otherwise, is there any way to get these two services to be able to access each other?

I was able to find a solution by passing the ingress URL via additional metadata and having the service use the URL in the meta data rather than the URL passed on by eureka. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#eureka-metadata-for-instances-and-clients
